Handle luigi task had failed dependencies
The goal is to catch an event when a Luigi task had failed dependencies and do some cleanup.
I have a boilerplate code where I raise an Exception when a tmp-file is being created. As a result of this we get the event 1 had failed dependencies. Having had on_failure function for ProcessData I expected that data.txt and data_tmp.txt have to be removed. But on_failure function is not triggered and the file data.txt remains in a folder. How can I handle the event  had failed dependencies properly?
Code:
import luigi
import os
import subprocess

class GenerateData(luigi.Task):
    output_path = luigi.Parameter(default='data.txt')

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.output_path)

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            for i in range(10):
                f.write("{}\n".format(i))


class GenerateTmpData(luigi.Task):
    output_path = luigi.Parameter(default='data_tmp.txt')

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.output_path)

    def run(self):
        raise BaseException("Simulated error in GenerateTmpData")
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            for i in range(10):
                f.write("{}\n".format(i))


class ProcessData(luigi.Task):
    input_path = luigi.Parameter(default='data.txt')
    input_tmp_path = luigi.Parameter(default='data_tmp.txt')
    output_path = luigi.Parameter(default='processed_data.txt')

    def requires(self):
        yield GenerateTmpData(output_path=self.input_tmp_path)
        yield GenerateData(output_path=self.input_path)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.output_path)

    def run(self):
        with self.input()[1].open('r') as infile, self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                number = int(line.strip())
                processed_number = number * 2
                outfile.write("{}\n".format(processed_number))

    def on_failure(self, exception):
        for item in self.input():
            if os.path.exists(item.path):
                os.remove(item.path)
        super(ProcessData, self).on_failure(exception)


def run_luigi_task():
    command = (
        'python -m luigi '
        '--module test ProcessData --local-scheduler '
    )
    subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_luigi_task()
    

Run as:
python test.py

Output:
DEBUG: Checking if ProcessData(input_path=data.txt, input_tmp_path=data_tmp.txt, output_path=processed_data.txt) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if GenerateTmpData(output_path=data_tmp.txt) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if GenerateData(output_path=data.txt) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   ProcessData_data_txt_data_tmp_txt_processed_data_t_ec6640af99   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   GenerateData_data_txt_1287d398ef   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   GenerateTmpData_data_tmp_txt_941f24e4a7   has status   PENDING
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 3
INFO: [pid 763] Worker Worker(salt=208102894, workers=1, host=8b0c89a2a184, username=root, pid=763) running   GenerateData(output_path=data.txt)
INFO: [pid 763] Worker Worker(salt=208102894, workers=1, host=8b0c89a2a184, username=root, pid=763) done      GenerateData(output_path=data.txt)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   GenerateData_data_txt_1287d398ef   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 2
INFO: [pid 763] Worker Worker(salt=208102894, workers=1, host=8b0c89a2a184, username=root, pid=763) running   GenerateTmpData(output_path=data_tmp.txt)
ERROR: [pid 763] Worker Worker(salt=208102894, workers=1, host=8b0c89a2a184, username=root, pid=763) failed    GenerateTmpData(output_path=data_tmp.txt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 199, in run
    new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 141, in _run_get_new_deps
    task_gen = self.task.run()
  File "test.py", line 25, in run
    raise BaseException("Simulated error in GenerateTmpData")
BaseException: Simulated error in GenerateTmpData
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   GenerateTmpData_data_tmp_txt_941f24e4a7   has status   FAILED
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
DEBUG: There are 2 pending tasks possibly being run by other workers
DEBUG: There are 2 pending tasks unique to this worker
DEBUG: There are 2 pending tasks last scheduled by this worker
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=208102894, workers=1, host=8b0c89a2a184, username=root, pid=763) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO: 
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 3 tasks of which:
* 1 ran successfully:
    - 1 GenerateData(output_path=data.txt)
* 1 failed:
    - 1 GenerateTmpData(output_path=data_tmp.txt)
* 1 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 had failed dependencies:
        - 1 ProcessData(input_path=data.txt, input_tmp_path=data_tmp.txt, output_path=processed_data.txt)

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====


